# Check if boolean has changed in Java

Tags: java, class, boolean, actionlistener

I have a class with a layout and a single button.  I was wondering if there was a built in method or functionality where I could detect if a booleans value had changed in the function.  I could do it with a mess of other booleans but was looking for a more elegant way.  I believe it has something to do with 'observers' but am not entirely sure.

a simplified version of the code is as follows:

```
Class checker{

 boolean test1 = true;
 boolean test2 = true;

checker(){

checkNow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{   

//code to manage, and possibly change the value of the booleans test1 and test2.
//is there any built in function in java where i can test to see if the value of the booleans was changed in this actionListener function?

}
}}); 

}
```

Answer (score 6):

> [is] there was a built in method or functionality where I could detect if a booleans value had changed in the function?

You can do it by encapsulating access to your `boolean` variables using setters:

```
private boolean test1 = true;
private boolean test2 = true;

private void setTest1(boolean newTest1) {
    if (newTest1 != test1) {
        // Do something
    }
}

private void setTest2(boolean newTest2) {
    if (newTest2 != test2) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Replace all assignments of these variables with calls of `setTest1` and `setTest2` to get reliable detection of changes in `test1` and `test2`.

Comment: thanks, i was doing something far more complicated with multiple booleans

Answer (score 1):

1) make the booleans private
2) access them via getters and setters
3) in the setter: 'if (this.val!=newVal) notify()'

Answer (score 0):

One option (which might be overkill) would be for the components that are interested in the change in the value of `test1` and `test2` implement a `PropertyChangeListener` and register to listen for when the values of these properties are changed.

Here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

Comment: You can use the PropertyChangeListener method in addition to dasblinkenlight's answer to notify other components when a property of your bean changes.